# Loop through multidimensional array in C#(Unity)

Tags: unity, c#, android, unityscript

I have this data

[image]

As you can see there's a 2nd board there.

Now what i want is something like this

**PSEUDO CODE**

```
If the first boards table[1,1] is not `NULL` then I will need to find out 
now if table[0,1] and table[0,0] has the same length as table[1,1] and 
table[1,0]

then display in the 2nd board a blue circle if it is the same in length if 
not red circle

But if the table[1,1] is `NULL` then I need to know compare 1st column and 
2nd column if they have the same length

then display in the 2nd board a blue circle if it is the same in length if 
not red circle
```

## END PSEUDO CODE

I tried doing the following

```
//COLUMN
    for(int col = 0; col < table.GetLength(0); col++)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        //ROW
        for (int row = 0; row < table.GetLength(1); row++)
        {
            if (table[col, row] != null)
            {
                Debug.Log("Column 1 has this value : " + table[col, row]);
            } 
        }
        //Debug.Log("table column: " + col + " has " + sum + " data");
    }
```

For now I can only get the whole Row and Column but I don't know how to do that pseudo code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//COLUMN
int prevSum = -1;
for (int col = 0; col < table.GetLength(0); ++col)
{

int sum = CountRow(table, col);
Debug.Log("table column :" + col + " has " + sum + " data");
if (sum == prevSum)
{
   prevSum = sum;
}

//generic function
public static int CountRow<T>(T[,] table, int col)
{
    if (table == null || col < 0 || col >= table.GetLength(1)) 
    {
        //handle error
        return -1;
    }

    //this is the same as the block of the outer for loop
    int sum = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < table.GetLength(1); row++)
    {
        if(table[col,row] != null)
        {
            sum++;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```